# Entity Framework validating errors

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to add personnel information to an automation with Entity, but when trying to add email information , Validating error evolves. What should i do?

error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

and my code:

```
CateringDBEntities sws = new CateringDBEntities();
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Personel sws2 = new Personel();
                sws2.p_name = textBox1.Text;
                sws2.p_sname = textBox2.Text;
                sws2.p_mail = textBox3.Text;
                sws.Personel.Add(sws2);
                sws.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Öğrenci Eklendi.");
                this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Add the problem code to your question along with the actual error message. That's the minimum information needed to help you fix the error.

Comment: Post the full exception string returned by `Exception.ToString()`, not just the message part. The full text contains the entire stack trace, any inner exceptions and quite often extra data that identifies the problem. A `DbEntityValidationException` also contains individual validation errors in the [EntityValidationErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationexception.entityvalidationerrors?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) property. The exception string will include these as well

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow swifty, please have a [tour] and learn [ask]. you should spare a little bit more time to understand how to make a [mcve]. we are unable to help you, if you cant be clear about your problems. oh right, just to be sure, the `Personel` only has 3 properties and you properly set them with valid values right?